# Design Pattern rich code base?

Tags: java, design-patterns, open-source, oop

Am new to design patterns, could you recommend a open code base (preferably in java) that has design patterns used explicitly and elegantly. Reading up GOF has left me confused am looking for a project that used a few patterns that interacted with each other.
thanks.

Comment: May I suggest you much better and reader friendly book with examples in Java? O'Reilly's Head First: Design Patterns (http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007126)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look at [JUnit](http://junit.org) and some of its [docs](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookstour/cookstour.htm). Also, JUnit is extremely useful tool by itself. I think any Java developer must know how to use it.

You can also find interesting conversation with Erich Gamma, posted on Artima.com:

1. [How to Use Design Patterns](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/gammadp.html)
2. [Erich Gamma on Flexibility and Reuse](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/reuse.html)
3. [Design Principles from Design Patterns](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/designprinciples.html)
4. [Patterns and Practice](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/patterns_practice.html)
5. [Eclipse's Culture of Shipping](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/eclipse_culture.html)

Maybe, not all parts of that conversation are relevant to your question, but they all are very interesting.

Comment: thanks Rorick, the doc was exactly the kind of example I was looking for

Comment: Glad to share) These docs were very useful for me.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than a code base, i will recomend the reading of [Head First design Patern](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007126) , by oreilly.
This books contains some really didactic exemple.

But the JDK is full of Design Pattern too. 
You can find Observer/observable , Iterator. Or more subtle, Decorator in the Java I/O API

[The google book link to Head first design pattern](http://books.google.fr/books?id=LjJcCnNf92kC&dq=head+first+design+patterns&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=fr&ei=HObVSsXqCoT54Ab72pDHDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CBkQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=&f=false)

Comment: Head first design patterns is very over rated, it's patterns dumbed down to much.  I spend to much of my time correcting miss conceptions created by this book.

Answer (score 2):

I think that there is not any code base with design patterns applied. This patterns are applied differently from project to project.

The pattern is a guide, a proven solution to a common programming or design problem that has been around in the development life cycle.

I would like to suggest to read the Head First Design Pattern book, it is very to the point and has a nice examples.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The JDK itself has some good examples.

For example, the `InputStream` / `OutputStream`, `Reader` / `Writer` implementations demonstrate usage of the decorator pattern, in the sense that you can wrap an OutputStream with another implementation in order to layer on additional functionality.

Answer (score 1):

http://userpages.umbc.edu/~tarr/dp/fall00/cs491.html

Answer (score 0):

May I recommend just looking at Wikipedia instead of GoF?  I found the book hard to read, but the [Wikipedia Article on Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science)) was awesomely useful for me.

It then drills down into useful examples, such as [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), [Lazy Initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization), [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and so on, all with good code examples, and all free.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to see how Patterns are applied in practice in the real world, the book 
[Core J2EE Patterns: Best Practices and Design Strategies (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131422464) is a bench mark book showing the main patterns used to produce real Web Application in java.